# JNDI lookup using java:app name gets NameNotFoundException even though the jndi is output

Tags: eclipse, jndi, wildfly

I have an ear file, RavenWeb which contains an ejb called RavenWeb_Bean.  When the server is started it outputs:

```
13:34:28,095 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-1) JNDI bindings for session bean named TerminalBean in deployment unit subdeployment "RavenWeb_Bean" of deployment "RavenWeb-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear" are as follows:

java:global/RavenWeb-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/RavenWeb_Bean/TerminalBean!com.scientificgames.raven.ejb.session.TerminalBean.TerminalBeanRemote
java:app/RavenWeb_Bean/TerminalBean!com.scientificgames.raven.ejb.session.TerminalBean.TerminalBeanRemote
java:module/TerminalBean!com.scientificgames.raven.ejb.session.TerminalBean.TerminalBeanRemote
java:jboss/exported/RavenWeb-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/RavenWeb_Bean/TerminalBean!com.scientificgames.raven.ejb.session.TerminalBean.TerminalBeanRemote
java:global/RavenWeb-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/RavenWeb_Bean/TerminalBean!com.scientificgames.raven.ejb.session.TerminalBean.TerminalBeanLocal
java:app/RavenWeb_Bean/TerminalBean!com.scientificgames.raven.ejb.session.TerminalBean.TerminalBeanLocal
java:module/TerminalBean!com.scientificgames.raven.ejb.session.TerminalBean.TerminalBeanLocal
```

Yet when I attempt a lookup from within the same project I receive:

13:34:51,957 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-122) com.scientificgames.raven.ejb.common.CommonBeanException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: java:app/RavenWeb_Bean/TerminalBean!com.scientificgames.raven.ejb.session.TerminalBean.TerminalBeanLocal

which exactly matches one of the lines in the startup output.

I initially was using java:global to find the resource but a change in JBoss tools renamed the ear file from RavenWeb.ear to RavenWeb-1.0.0.SNAPSHOT.ear which then threw off the lookup.
Im not sure what else to attach other than the log messages.

Edit: After some more debugging I have found htat javax.naming.InitialContext.findContext()'s call to selector.getContext() is returning null which is what is causing the NameNotFoundException to be thrown.

Edit: Lookup Code

```
public static Object getLocalBean(Class<? extends CommonBean> commonBeanClass) throws CommonBeanException
{
    try
    {
        String localInterfaceClassName = null;
        for (Class<?> implementedInterface : commonBeanClass.getInterfaces()) {
            if (implementedInterface.isAnnotationPresent(Local.class)) {
                localInterfaceClassName = implementedInterface.getName();
                break;
            }
        }
        if (localInterfaceClassName == null) {
            throw new CommonBeanException("Could not locate @Local interface for " + commonBeanClass);
        }

        return InitialContext.doLookup("java:app/RavenWeb_Bean/" + commonBeanClass.getSimpleName() + "!" + localInterfaceClassName);
    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
    {
        throw new CommonBeanException(e);
    }
    catch (NamingException e)
    {
        throw new CommonBeanException(e);
    }
    catch (SecurityException e)
    {
        throw new CommonBeanException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, from ehere are you looking up the bean? from within the same EAR or from another application? Please post also your lookup code. Thanks

Comment: I am looking up the bean from within the same ejb as the beans definition.